No se integrar QStakedWidget en mi interfaz
Soy un novato en el tema de la programación, aunque en el futuro tengo planeado estudiar eso. Llevo un tiempo aprendiendo Python y hace unos dias me interesé por las interfaces, en concreto PyQT5.
Estoy creando una app como si fuera de una tienda, de momento estoy creando el login, pero necesito que al pulsar un boton, la pantalla cambie a la vista con el login.
He investigado y he descubierto que existe QStackedWidget, que parece a primera vista que es lo que necesito para mi app, pero por mas que intento integrarlo, no consigo que la aplicacion inicie. Antes iniciaba con normalidad, ahora no inicia y no tira ningun error.
Dejo aqui el link de github con el proyecto: https://github.com/ChiplinElGnomo/grandblueshop/blob/test/main.py
Para ser lo mas especifico posible, ahora mismo deberia de aparecer la ventana principal al iniciar. En esa ventana hay 2 botones y 2 label, uno con la imagen de fondo y otro con un cartel en la parte superior. Al pulsar el boton "botonempleados" deberian desaparecer los botones y aparecer el login.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Hola Cristian, bienvenido a [es.so]. Una recomendación, debes siempre intentar agregar un [emcv] directamente a la pregunta, añadir al menos el código en el que creas que está el problema como texto al contenido de la misma. Esto es así porque si el día de mañana el recurso externo (el repositorio) deja de existir la pregunta quedaría sin contexto y podría dejar de ser útil a otros usuarios futuros.Obviamente no siempre vas a poder agregarlo todo, por lo que si pones un enlace al repo en GitHub con el proyecto completo como haces no está mal, se agradece y nos facilitas las cosas enormemente.

Dicho esto, acabo de probar tu código y funciona a la perfección en mi caso  (Python 3.13, PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.15), exactamente como describes que debería funcionar. Descarta que no sea un problema del IDE o de tu sistema.

Efectivamente era un problema del IDE, al reiniciarlo se solucionó, lo raro es que tuve que reiniciarlo varias veces para que funcionara. Gracias por la respuesta.
